# Fetch a word starting with a particular pattern from Word doc using c#

Tags: c#, office-interop, doc

This is my code

```
             Word.Range rng = document.Content;
             rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
             rng.Find.Forward = true;
             rng.Find.Text = strKey;

             rng.Find.Execute(
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
             while (rng.Find.Found)
            {
                string temp = rng.Find.ToString();
            }
```

Suppose I have a pattern like "ID_" which I have stored in strKey. 
I intend to read the string which starts with the above pattern. In the above code I only tend to get the pattern but not the entire string. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add

```
rng.Find.MatchPrefix = true;
```

Its allow to match words beginning with the search string.
It`s maybe useful reference with full list of properties of Find interface https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find_members.aspx